# How was this formula arrived?

Tags: combinatorics

If i need chose groups of $n$ elements of a $m$, where $m \geq n$, we can solve by this way:

Example:

> I have $5$ players, and I want to make groups of $3$, how many can I do?

Then, there are 5 players ($m$) and each player can make groups with the other $4$ players, and each one of these $4$ players can make groups with the other $3$, then the result is: $5 * 4 * 3 = 60$

With an analysis, problem like this can be solved with:

$V^m_n = m(m - 1)(m -2) ...(m - n + 1)$

I have been looking for intuitive and / or logical demonstrations, I have not found any.

So, how can I get from $V^m_n = m(m - 1)(m -2) ...(m - n + 1)$, to:

$V^m_n = \frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$

I have also been trying, and I have deduced that when i use $V^m_n = m(m - 1)(m -2) ...(m - n + 1)$, the amount of binomials create are $(n - 1)$, that are (m - 1) (m - 2) up to (m - n + 1)

PD: The idea is to prove it, ignoring that the formula existed.

Comment: $\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}=\frac{m(m-1)...(m-n)!}{(m-n)!}=m(m-1)...(m-n+1)$

Comment: Verbe, can you explain, please

Comment: @Mattiu Is your question to show that $$m(m-1)\cdots(m-n+1)=\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$$?

Comment: Yes, how to get that,  but without knowing that it should be $\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$

Comment: Well. $(m-n)!=(m-n)(m-n-1)(m-n-2)...1$ by definition. So simplifying numerator and denominator by deleting common factors in my previous comment yields your formula.

Comment: From $m(m-1)$ until $m(m-1)...(m-n+1)$, So, where do you get $ (m - n)! $, If the last term is $ (m - n + 1) $

Comment: Hi Mattiu: Try looking at some small examples and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: I suppose your question is the rather philosophical one "how to see the formula?". But the formula is nothing more than a clever rewriting of 
$m(m-1)...(m-n+1)$.

Comment: Yes, so what is that intelligent way?

Comment: $m(m-1)...(m-n+1)*\frac{1}{1}=m(m-1)...(m-n+1)*\frac{(m-n)!}{(m-n)!}=\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$.

Comment: Okay.   so you have a string of numbers $k*(k*1)*(k+2)*.......*(n-2)*(n-1)*n$ and you think "gee, that's a pain to write! Do we have any notation for the product of consecutive numbers?"  And we think "well, obviously we have $n!$.  But that's not good because it goes all the way to to $1$ and we only want to go to $k$.  So how do we get rid of the 'tail'?"  And we think "well the tail we want to get rid of is $1*2*....*(k-1)$ and that's just $(k-1)!$".  So we think.  "Let's just divide the tail out:  $k*.... *n = \frac {1*....*(k-1)}{1*....*(k-1)}*k*...*n=\frac {n!}{(k-1)!}$".

Comment: You should start writing stories for toddlers :-)

Comment: I think I'm a small child, because that intuitive explanation has been much more useful @Verbe

Comment: @Mattiu No offense! It is a nice explanation and a good question to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $m! = m*(m-1)*(m-2)*.......*3*2*1$.

And by definition $(m-n)! = (m-n)*(m-n-1)*(m-n-2)*....... * 3*2 *1$.

So $\frac {m!}{(m-n)!} = $

$\frac {m*(m-1)*(m-2)*.......*3*2*1}{(m-n)*(m-n-1)*(m-n-2)*....... * 3*2 *1}=$

$\frac {m*(m-1)*(m-2)*...*(m-n+2)(m-n+1)(m-n)(m-n-1)(m-n-2)*....*3*2*1}{(m-n)*(m-n-1)*(m-n-2)*....... * 3*2 *1}=$

$\frac {m*(m-1)*(m-2)*...*(m-n+2)(m-n+1)\color{red}{(m-n)(m-n-1)(m-n-2)*....*3*2*1}}{\color{red}{(m-n)*(m-n-1)*(m-n-2)*....... * 3*2 *1}}=$

$m*(m-1)*(m-2)*...(m-n+2)(m-n+1)$.

Ex: $\frac {17!}{8!} = $

$\frac {17*16*15*14*13*12*11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1}{8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1}=$

$\frac  {17*16*15*14*13*12*11*10*9*\color{red}{8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1}}{\color{red}{8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1}}= $

$17*16*15*14*13*12*11*10*9$.

....

In a similar vein if $k < n$ we can *always* know that $k!|n!$ and $\frac {n!}{k!} = (k+1)(k+2)*....*(n-1)*n$

And that $n! = k!*(k+1)(k+2)*....*(n-1)*n$.

These are all considered to be inherent.

Comment: Really, your comment was perfect, many many thanks fleablood

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

What can you multiply $m(m-1)(m-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(m-n+1)$ with, to get $m!$? Now, multiply with that same quantity in the denominator.

---

Edit: You have $m$ elements to choose from, and you want to make a group consisting of $n$ elements, in how many ways can you do this? Look at the 1st element of this group, in how many ways can you choose this element? This amount is $m$. Having chosen the 1st element, there are $m-1$ elements to chose the 2nd element from, and so on ... You do this until you have chosen $n-1$th element, and now there are only $m-(n-1)=m-n+1$ elements left for the $n$th element. In total there are $$m(m-1)(m-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot (m-n+1)$$ ways.

Comment: The idea is to prove it, ignoring that the formula existed, you want to get $m!$ because you already know the formula

Comment: I've updated my answer, but it is not clear what you're asking. What do you want to prove? Do you want to prove that $m(m-1)(m-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot (m-n+1)=\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$, this is just algebra. Or do you want to prove that the number of ways to make a group of $n$ members from $m$ elements is $\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}$?

Comment: I want to know how to arrive from $m(m-1)(m-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot (m-n+1)$ to $\frac{m!}{(m-n)!},$, but they show it to me, because they know they have to simplify and get to $ \frac {m!} {(M - n)!} $, But my idea is to get the formula, without previously knowing that I should get there. Place yourself in the place of the inventor of the formula, he not know that the formula exist, because he invented it

Comment: By writing the right hand sight in full and then cancelling out common factors. Like $\frac{5!}{3!}=\frac{5*4*3*2*1}{3*2*1}=5*4$.

Answer (score 0):

> I have $5$ players, and I want to make groups of $3$, how many can I do?

What you described is called permutation: choosing $3$ players out of $5$ players, when the order is important. (You can compare it with combination, when the order of selection is not important).

> I have been looking for intuitive and / or logical demonstrations, I have not found any.

Call the players $A,B,C,D,E$.

We want to choose $3$ players from $5$ players in different orderings. You described the solution correctly:

> Then, there are 5 players (m) and each player can make groups with the other 4 players, and each one of these 4 players can make groups with the other 3, then the result is: 5∗4∗3=60.

Now let's look at the process of selection from different perspective.

There are $5!$ ways to choose $5$ players from $5$ players in different orderings (it is called ordered permutation). For example, $ABCDE$; $ABCED$;$\ \cdots \ $; $EDCBA$. That is $5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$.

We are interested in the first $3$ players we choose and do not care about the **ordering** of the rest $2$ players. That is:
$$\begin{align}&ABC\color{red}{DE} \ \ (ABC\color{red}{ED})\\
&ABD\color{red}{CE} \ \ (ABD\color{red}{EC}) \\
&\qquad \qquad \vdots\\
&EDC\color{red}{AB} \ \ (EDC\color{red}{BA})
\end{align}\\$$
Note that once we choose $ABC$, it does not matter if the rest two are $DE$ or $ED$. Also note that all orderings of $5$ players were $5!$ and it is now divided by half (that is the orderings of the last two players, that is $2!$).

Hence, to find the (ordered) permutation of $5$ players chosen $3$ at a time is:
$$P(5,3)=\frac{5!}{2!}=\frac{5!}{(5-3)!}.$$

Practice question: How many ways can you choose $7$ players out of $10$ players, when the order is important?

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this is totally irrelevant ..

Comment: You are welcome. Please, come back to this answer when you do more practice on permutations and combinations. Good luck.